# Use ATTRIB command over a batch itself

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, file-attributes, attributes

Well, this is the thing, i have this in my batch file:

```
attrib +R +H +S "%STARTUP%\%0"
icacls "%STARTUP%\%0" /deny *S-1-1-0:^(DE,WA^) *S-1-5-7:^(DE,WA^)
attrib +R "%STARTUP%\%0"
icacls "%STARTUP%\%0" /deny *S-1-1-0:^(DE,DC,WA^) *S-1-5-7:^(DE,DC,WA^)
```

Im getting Access deny on the first attrib command, but icacls says 0 errors what is normal if you consider that im not changing the execution permission.
I didnt find much info about this toppic, the closest that i found was [How a batch file can delete itself and exit the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035706/how-a-batch-file-can-delete-itself-and-exit-the-command-prompt) and [How to make a batch file delete itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329355/how-to-make-a-batch-file-delete-itself)

PD: I search for that becouse this four lines are at the very bottom of my .bat, so, maybe if i exit and then use the attrib command, maybe but i try it with no success.
I try:

```
set temptrue=true
(goto) 2>nul & if %temptrue% equ true (
    attrib +R +H +S "%STARTUP%\%0"
    icacls "%STARTUP%\%0" /deny *S-1-1-0:^(DE,WA^) *S-1-5-7:^(DE,WA^)
    attrib +R "%STARTUP%\%0"
    icacls "%STARTUP%\%0" /deny *S-1-1-0:^(DE,DC,WA^) *S-1-5-7:^(DE,DC,WA^)
)
```

Regards, TYA.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidPostill im trying to make this same file unable to be deleted for the normal user, is for a freezing program that im trying to do. If i run this commands one by one on a CMD when the rest of the batch ended, all works perfect, but if i integrate on the same batch, it fails.

Comment: There is no `%startup%`. Did you make it up. Your whole approach is quite silly. Type in *Run* dialog `shell:Common Start Menu`. Put your shortcut here when you are an admin. That's all you need do.

Comment: @user1292580 i create %startup%, thats not the point of the problem